# Creating virtualenv with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I generally use `python2.7` for projects.

For one project, I need to use `python 3.5+`.

I installed python3 on Mac.

Also installed `virtualenv` using pip3.

Now when I run the command

```py
virtualenv -p python3 test
```

I get the following error:

```py
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Already using interpreter /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/test/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/test/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2632, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 870, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1156, in create_environment
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1621, in install_python
    shutil.copy(original_python, py_executable)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copyfile
    if _samefile(src, dst):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 88, in _samefile
    return os.path.samefile(src, dst)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 96, in samefile
    s1 = os.stat(f1)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

Comment: I think for mac it is "virtualenv yourenvname -p python3.6"

Comment: Check version of pip3 and update, then update virtualenv. This is an old issue that should be resolved

Comment: Also, to avoid headaches, I would recommend you to take a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). It helps you manage several versions of Python on the same system. You can for example make Python 3.x by default instead of the antique 2.7 of macOS.

Comment: I confirm what @KentMartin said. Upgrading virtualenv works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For making a virtual environment with Python 3

Use this for making `env`

```py
python3 -m venv env
```

To activate `env`

```py
source env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve upon answer of @ParthS007 (Wanted to add a comment to the existing answer but couldn't due to not enough reputation):

1. Corrected the virtual environment name to be the common used one `venv` so it's easier for beginners like me to use/understand in conjunction with other tutorials.
2. Added how to deactivate and remove virtual environment too.

> For making a virtual environment with Python 3
>
> Use this for making env
>
> `python3 -m venv venv`
>
> To activate env
>
> `source env/bin/activate`

To deactivate env

`deactivate`

To remove env

`rm -rf venv`